# convert my string to unique code and store in db and get back original name to view the data c#

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, unique

For c#,

I have to change my column names as some unique code with defined length and move it to database. Getting back the column name and view by its original name.

I have checked encryption and decryption concepts. Its encrypted string length get difference for my input strings and more than 64 characters if input is long.

I need the encrypted string length for all input values should not be greater than 64 characters

In Hashing concept it returns difference output value of equal or lesser than 64 characters length of hashed string but unable to get back my original string.

Share the API details if any available.

example,

[image]

here encrypted strings are in within 64 characters length.

Comment: I recommend to use Rijndael to do your task.

Comment: @Arphile while using Rijndael unable to get the all encrypted strings at unique length.? It will be differs if my input string was larger

Comment: how about using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators for task?

Comment: What is the use of bitwise here? @Arphile

Comment: "I need the encrypted string length for all input values must be same." Why?

Comment: Interesting.  1. Are the inputs equal in length?  2.What is the accepted maximum length of the outputs?

Comment: @ZoharPeled i have to maintain some unique name for column names and move to DB. column name length greater than 128 bytes are not allowed in SQL server. Like that for MySQL, Oracle, Postgres having some limits in that column length.

Comment: @JQSOFT  1. Inputs are not in same length 
2. Output maximum length i needed 64 characters

Comment: Ok, but why do you need the encrypted text have the same length? Why wouldn't a maximum length for encrypted text be good enough?

Comment: Yes Okay. Its fine. I need the maximum length of 64 characters in encrypted string

Comment: This sound like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need encryption ? Do you need to protect something ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen i don't need to protect anything. I need unique name with max length of 64 characters for each input string. because to avoid duplication in column names in DB